# After Ajax load no click function with jquery and bootstrap / Photogallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Tank you!

i have a new problem ajax load this (ajax.php):

```
<div class="wall-img-preview lightbox clearfix">
<div class="wip-item" data-src="media/gallery/2.jpg" style="background-image: url(media/gallery/2.jpg);" data-sub-html="<em><h3>This is a caption heading</h3><p>Here goes the description...</p></em>">
<img src="media/gallery/thumbs/2.jpg">
</div>
</div>
```

But no click function (Photogallery with swipefunction with jquery, bootstrap etc...) this is my ajax script:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: 'appajax.php', data: parameter, 
    success: function(data) 
        {
        // $('#'+id).html(data);
        $('#'+id).html(data).row("refresh");
        }
    });
```

i try with tigger and refresh but nu succsses :( Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your English.

From what I understood, your problem is hanging of page after `ajax` load. Please try replacing the code with below code

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: 'appajax.php', async:false, data: parameter, 
success: function(data) 
    {
    // $('#'+id).html(data);
    $('#'+id).html(data).row("refresh");
    }
});
```

`async` function will prevent `DOM` get hang.

Comment: Hi Arun, i try 
When the page loads, it works after the ajax updated range it no longer works but it will all but displayed one kan not open the photo